# Making x data the size of y data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of temperatures that are updating once every second and what I am ultimately hoping to do is make a real time plot that will be able to replace the old data with the new data as it is being taken. Essentially, I want to take a ton of data and have the graph real time plot it but only show the most recent 100 data points. I have devised the code seen below but I am unsure how to append the xdata in order for it to be the same length as the ydata. I keep getting the error "xdata and ydata must be the same length." If there are any easier ways to do what I want please let me know of that as well.

```
temperature = []
x = list()
y = list()
x1 = list()
y1 = list()

# Read loop
for i in range(1000):
    # Get the thermocouple reading on AIN0. 
    tempC = ljm.eReadName(handle, "AIN0_EF_READ_A")
    temperature.append(tempC)
    dT = temperature[i]-temperature[i-1]

    if -.5<dT<.5:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT, "         " "Steady State" 
        sleep(1)
    else:
        print "Temperature:","%.3f"% temperature[i],"         " "dT:", "%.3f"% dT
        sleep(1) 

    x.append(i)
    y.append(temperature[i])

    x1.append(i)
    y1.append(dT)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    li, = ax.plot(x,y)


    # draw and show it
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.show(block=False)

    # loop to update the data
    while True:
        try:
            y[:-10] = y[10:]
            y.append(temperature[i])

            # set the new data
            li.set_ydata(y)

            fig.canvas.draw()

            sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

Comment: You are appending data to `y` using `y.append(temperature[i])` twice but only appending to `x` once. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Probably not but I am not sure how to append x as I did y. Any suggestions?

Comment: within your `while True` loop, possibly just do `x = range(len(y))`  (I'm literally guessing here -- this is the sort of thing that you should be trying on your own and debugging to see *why* the lists are different lengths, and what might be done about it, etc.) Note that again, you may need to do *additional* changes to your `li` object or re-draw the `fix.canvas`, or re-assign `li, = ax.plot(x,y)`  etc., these sort of things you need to work out on your own...